# What is the probability that L does not intersect C1?

Tags: probability, geometry, geometric-probability

Let C1 and C2 be two concentric circles with radius r and 2r respectively. Given a fixed point Q on the circumference of C2, a line L is drawn at random going through Q. What is the probability that L does not intersect C1?

I tried using geometry to calculate probability whereby ratio of segment area to the overall area of C2 should be the answer. However I am not getting the right solution. It seems to be straightforward question unless I am missing something obvious.

Comment: Hint: Assume that point Q has cartesian coordinates (0,2r) and that the center of the circles is at point (0,0).  Then the line passing through point Q will have a *heading* of some random number in $[0^{\circ},360^{\circ}).$  Therefore, the question reduces to determining the angle(s) made by the lines tangent to the inner circle that pass through the point Q.  A right triangle is formed by the line (0,0)<-->(0,2r), one of the tangent lines that passes through point Q, and the connection of the tangent line to the origin.  All you have to do is determine the angles of this right triangle.

Comment: Thanks. I was using the same logic but was using area instead of angle.

Answer (score 1):

When looking all around, the angle scanned is $2 \pi$ radians. Area scanned is infinite, independent variable should be the azimuth scan angle $\theta$ that has to be partitioned.

[image]

$$ \theta= \sin^{-1}\frac12= \dfrac{\pi}{6}$$

What is seen is (white)$ 2 \theta$

What is not seen is (yellow) $ 2 \pi-2 \theta$

So the unseen yellow fraction is

$$1-\dfrac{1}{6}=\dfrac{5}{6}.$$

Comment: Which software did you use to draw the image sir?

Comment: Paint, but it has no arbitrary rotatin. Labels Mathjax,

Comment: thanks a lot...

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Note that we have to consider angles as probability and not length.

Angle subtended by APB is $\pi/6$. (from trigonometry, sin 30=0.5). So the probability will be $(\pi-\pi/6)/pi)$ (as it is line, we need to consider both ends, hence total possible angles of rotation  are $\pi$ and not $2\pi$)

so answer must be $5/6$=0.8334

Hope you will be able to carry on

Comment: yes. wrote 60 in hurry... sorry for that corrected it now...thx